# Svelte component async loading in version 3

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I would like to ask you a question about updating a simple example from version 2 to version 3.

This example of svelte v2 async component loading works (https://codesandbox.io/s/0ooo3z8nqp), but this one written for v3 doesn't (https://codesandbox.io/s/615zv3xp33).

Any clue?
Thanks!

**Update:** 
My question was about converting the following piece of code from Svelte V2 to V3.

```js
<script>
    export default {
      components: {},
      data() {
        return {
          ChatBox: null
        };
      },
      methods: {
        async loadChatbox() {
          const { default: ChatBox } = await import("./Chatbox.html");
          this.set({ ChatBox });
        }
      }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In version 3 of Svelte you can assign a new value to the variable directly without using `set`.

You can name the `default` to something other than `ChatBox` so that the outer variable isn't shadowed, and then assign directly to it.

```js
let ChatBox;

async function loadChatBox() {
  const { default: Component } = await import("./ChatBox.svelte");
  ChatBox = Component;
}
```